# Solving a discrete log with BsGs

Tags: discrete-logarithm

If we consider a group G with modulus p, order q with $p=2*q+1$, and generator $g=2$ ($ p$, $q$ huge prime numbers), is there a way to solve the discrete log problem $ g^x = y $ for a y given, using the baby steps giant step algorithm AND the fact that $x$ is of the form: $ x = \sum_{i=0}^{10} \alpha_i * 2^i $  $:\alpha_i \in \mathbb{N} $ without requiring to store all small steps in a hashtable, which is impossible with the magnitude of the numbers $p$ and $q$.

edit:
The $ \alpha_i $ values are unknown to the attacker.

edit 2: $\alpha_i \in [0,\infty] $

Comment: Does the attacker know the $\alpha_i$ values?

Comment: Does actually $\alpha_i \in \{0,1\}$? Does $\mathbb{N} = \mathbb{Z}^+$ or $\mathbb{N} = \mathbb{Z}^+ \cup \{0\}$, there is no common agreement on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there a way to solve the discrete log problem $g^x=y$ for a $y$ given, using the baby steps giant step algorithm

No practical way if $p, q$ are large.

> Even if $x$ is known to be in the form $ x = \sum_{i=0}^{10} \alpha_i * 2^i $  $:\alpha_i \in \mathbb{N} $ ?

Every potential $x$ can be expressed in that form; consider $\alpha_1 = \alpha_2 = ... = \alpha_{10} = 0$ and $\alpha_{0} = x$.  Hence, knowing that $x$ is expressable in that form does not provide any additional information; BsGs is usable only if the modulus is small enough (and the question assumes it is not)

Comment: No $x< 2048$. The problem is much easier, you can do Bruteforce attack (but without babystep/giant step).

Comment: @levgeni: if we're talking about values that **can** be expressed in that form, we have $x \ge 2047$ (and that's with the convention that $0 \not\in \mathbb{N}$; otherwise, all $x$ values can be expressed in that form).

Comment: @levgeni: and, if $x < 2048$ and $p$ is cryptographically sized (i.e. at least 2048 bits), the discrete log can be extracted directly from the value $2^x$; that has bit $x$ as 1, and all the other bits as 0...

Comment: @poncho I think levgeni argues that even if $x>2046$, it doesn't imply that $x$ is not trivially small. The large is clear, however the small need a metric.

Comment: @kelalaka: I don't understand your argument; if we interpret the question of "is DLog solvable if we assume the exponent is random, conditioned by being expressable in the given form?"  With that understanding, my answer is correct - how do you interpret the question?

Comment: @poncho if $x$ is small ( no metric here ) but we know the bound, then BsGs can be parametrized to solve faster, right? And again, if $x$ is small then actually we don't need BsGs, we can brute-force it like we can brute-force from 1 to $2^{48}$ for possible $x$'. Or, are you implicitly assuming $x$ uniform random?

Comment: @poncho Ok, I thought the $\alpha$'s were bits. I'm a little bit lost with all the edits. I still do not understand why you spoke about $2046$. I would like to delete my $-1$, but I can only if you edit your message.

Comment: @levgeni: if $0 \not\in \mathbb{N}$, then the minimum $\sum_1^{10} 2^i\alpha_i$ can be is 2046.  Some definitions of $\mathbb{N}$ do not include 0, others do.

Comment: But the sum in the question begins to zero, so it should be $2047$?

Comment: @levgeni: I'm using $\alpha_0$ as the value that changes, and so we effectively have $x = \alpha_0 + 2046$ - $\alpha_0 = 0$ is not allowed, so we have $x > 2046$

Comment: @Ievgeni : Okay, Thx for the explanation. I understood. But it seems that finally the $alpha$'s can be equal to zero.